# Can I import/use a vsix file in SharpDevelop?

Tags: c#, vsix, sharpdevelop

I have a project template in the form of a `vsix` extension for Visual Studio which I would like to use to start a new project.

My first intention was to use Visual Studio Community 2015 but the install process is blocked by my company's firewall. The IT guys in charge are very slow at dealing with this sort of queries so I decided to try SharpDevelop.

I haven't been able to find anything about importing/converting a `vsix` extension to something useable in SharpDevelop.

The extension I am trying to use should consist only of a few templates and a list of libraries.

Could I somehow import/use this template in SharpDevelop?

Comment: Doubtful, vsix is a visual studio extension, and not a SharpDevelop addin. Unless SharpDevelop has a way to emulate vsix extensions, I don't think there is a way to run vsix without visual studio.

Comment: @Wazner I was hoping I could somehow unzip the `vsix` file and get the templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the .VSIX extension to .ZIP and use any zip browser (including the Windows File Explorer) to browse its contents.